# how to fetch json data from a remote server in a backbone.js app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, backbone.js

I'm following an app example from this [repo](https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-directory)
and i started to build a similar app in my local machine using rails intead php for API, so i build apart the rails app in a specific root directory then in another root the backbone.js/JQM app calling rails api.

so i create the model and the collection in backbone with the urlRoot with: http://localhost:3000/api/clubs.json, that correspond to the local server url for retrieve a list of clubs

then i have tried to see in the javascript console what happen with these commands:

```
clubs = new ClubsCollection()

Object {length = 0 ...etc..}

clubs.fetch()
GET http://localhost:3000/api/clubs.json 200 OK
```

and the response is empty...

but when i call the url  http://localhost:3000/api/clubs.json it returns the json clubs list correctly.

can you help me to understand the best way to do this call?

Comment: Are you sure you are not having any _cross-domain_ issue?, check the _Network_ browser console.

Comment: i don't know, everything runs locally, but in two different services, one is the rails server the other apache.

Comment: Are you agile with your browser's developer panel?, which browser are you using?

Comment: i'm using firefox with firebug, in fact the code that i have posted is the code that i wrote into the firebug console

Comment: What does the log on the Rails layer is showing when you make the request?

Comment: Started GET "/api/clubs.json" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon May 07 16:40:34 +0200 2012
Processing by ClubsController#index as JSON
  Club Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "clubs".* FROM "clubs" 
Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 24.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: Let's try to move this conversation to a chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10975/question-10482873

Comment: my reputation is under 20, i can't chat :-(

Comment: try now :).. I have upvoted one of your previous questions

Comment: i'm still not able to chat...

Comment: :/.. what about here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10978/discussion-between-davelab-and-fguillen

Comment: Well, What I wanted to propose is to search where the response starts to be empty, could be nice to print out the json response in the Rails layer to see if is already empty there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem using ['rack-cors' gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) with the a basic config into

*config/application.rb:*

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins 'localhost'
        resource '%r{/api/\$+.json}',
          :headers => ['Origin', 'Accept', 'Content-Type'],
          :methods => [:get, :put, :delete]
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is asynchronous. you have to wait for it to finish loading the data, and check the response then. This is typically done through the `reset` event:

```
clubs = new ClubsCollection();
clubs.on("reset", function(){
  alert(clubs.length + " item(s) found");
});
clubs.fetch();
```

Comment: the new istance of ClubsCollection that i did is on the firebug console so i don't think that is necessary to call the bind/on method

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the backbone API there is a success callback that you can provide with the fetch() call, e.g.

clubs.fetch({ 
   success : function(model, err) { // do something }
});

Like the other answer, fetch is asynchronous so you can't expect the results to be back by setting a break point after the .fetch() call.